# PHP Login Form Session Variable Destroying

Tags: php, web

I am new to PHP and I am creating a login screen with a session variable. I am trying to destroy or unset my session variable when logging out but it doesn't seem to work.

My session variable:

```
$_SESSION['CurrentUser']
```

This is the button which should end the session:

```
<input type="submit" name="logout" id="logout" value="Log out">
```

When pressing a button:

```
if(isset($_POST['logout']))
{
    session_unset();  
    session_destroy(); 
}
```

Comment: Is the session started? How and where do you set the session to begin with?

Comment: make sure you call session_start(); first

Comment: Yeah session is started and works fine.

Comment: The form method is 'post' ?

Comment: Yes method is post

Comment: To logout you should redirect to logout page to destroy the session, so on future requests the session is empty, in case you logout on the main page you would see the last session data.

Answer (score 1):

My good practice, is to set the session variable to something random:

```
$_SESSION['CurrentUser'] = time();
session_destroy();
```

and then reload/refresh the page. For example:

```
header('Location: /');
die;
```

If you do not redirect after session destruction, the page will render *as if* the session was not destroyed (html will render...)

Comment: Best practice on my opinion is empty all the session if you just want to destroy it, like: `$_SESSION = [];` and then destroy. :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried the method of [GET], it works!

I'm not sure if the method of [POST] could be OK, because my PhpStorm may be not normal, so I want to try IIS instead, but the fastCGI can't work at this time.

So you can solve the problem by using [GET] method, just like this:

```
<form method="get" action="xxxx.php">
    <input type="submit" name="logout" value="Log out">
</form>
```

That's all.